# Initialize Alert Outside Body View - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, alert

Been trying to figure this out for a few days now and it's time I ask for help. I know how to do this with normal Swift but SwiftUI is still a bit different to me at the moment. I have a function that checks if something is true. It goes through 3 if statements, if one is true then it returns a bool I created as true. Once one of the 3 is true, I want a certain Alert to pop up. I have pasted all 3 Alert in the body: some View with the correct variable but it doesn't show any. If I comment out 2 and leave 1 Alert uncommented then it works. So I know my if statements are right. It's just how I'm representing it to the body is where I'm stuck at. See below and if you got an alternative.

```
    func showTip() {
            if (stepFive <= Float(18)) {
                under = true
            }

           else if (stepFive >= Float(18) && stepFive <= Float(18.5)) {
                thin = true
            }


           else if (stepFive >= 18.6) && (stepFive <= 24.9) {
                healthy = true
            }
    }

var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            .alert(isPresented: $under) {
                Alert(title: Text("Results"), message: Text("A of less than 18 means you are under weight. "), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }

            .alert(isPresented: $thin) {
                Alert(title: Text("Results"), message: Text("A of less than 18.5 indicates you are thin"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }

            .alert(isPresented: $healthy) {
                Alert(title: Text("Results"), message: Text("A between 18.6 and 24.9 indicates you are at a healthy"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** for showing solution with `showTip` function:

```swift
struct ComplexAlertWith3Variables: View {

    @State var under = false
    @State var thin = false
    @State var healthy = false
    @State var stepFive: Float = 18.3 // I don't know how it changes. From somewhere. and it doesn't matter now

    private var messageText: String {
        return thin ? "A of less than 18.5 indicates you are thin" : "" // compute other variants
    }

    var body: some View {

        let needToShowAlert: Binding<Bool> = Binding<Bool>(
        get: { self.under || self.thin || self.healthy },
        set: { if $0 == false { self.under = $0; self.thin = $0; self.healthy = $0 } })

        return Text("Fire show tip function, because I don't know from where it fires in your code")
            .onTapGesture { self.showTip() } // fire your function. so you see, it doesn't matter from where you change variables
            .alert(isPresented: needToShowAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Results"), message: Text(self.messageText), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }

    }

    // your function (makes it shorter to fit more lines of code)
    func showTip() {
        if (stepFive <= Float(18)) { under = true } 
        else if (stepFive >= Float(18) && stepFive <= Float(18.5)) { thin = true }
        else if (stepFive >= 18.6) && (stepFive <= 24.9) { healthy = true }
    }
}
```

result when you tap on text **OR** fires function from some other place:

[image]

I played with this a little and I think I can propose you one solution. It's about [making custom `Binding` variable](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/creating-custom-bindings-in-swiftui) and using it in `body`. Besides in first variant I wrote decision with `enum`, but you can find solution with 3 variables in code snippet too:

```swift
struct ComplexAlert: View {

    @State private var option: SomeOption = .unselected

    var body: some View {
        // DISCLAIMER: I wrote in a such a way to fit more lines of code on the page
        // the main here is an idea, not code style =)
        let needToShowAlert: Binding<Bool> = Binding<Bool>(
            get: { self.option != .unselected },
            set: { if $0 == false { self.option = .unselected } })

        return VStack {
            Button(action: { self.option = .under }) { Text("make under") }
            Button(action: { self.option = .thin }) { Text("make thin") }
            Button(action: { self.option = .healthy }) { Text("make healthy") }
        }
            .alert(isPresented: needToShowAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Results"), message: Text(self.option.getAlertMessage()), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }
}

// MARK: if you need to use 3 variables:
struct ComplexAlertWith3Variables: View {

    @State var under = false
    @State var thin = false
    @State var healthy = false

    private var messageText: String {
        return under ? "under" : "" // compute other varianst
    }

    var body: some View {

        let needToShowAlert: Binding<Bool> = Binding<Bool>(
        get: { self.under || self.thin || self.healthy },
        set: { if $0 == false { self.under = $0; self.thin = $0; self.healthy = $0 } })

        return Text("Hello")
            .onTapGesture { self.under = true }
            .alert(isPresented: needToShowAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Results"), message: Text(self.messageText), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }

    }
}

// MARK: enum which was used in the first solution:
enum SomeOption {

    case unselected
    case under
    case thin
    case healthy

    func getAlertMessage() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .unselected:
            return ""
        case .under:
            return "A of less than 18 means you are under weight. "
        case .thin:
            return "A of less than 18.5 indicates you are thin"
        case .healthy:
            return "A between 18.6 and 24.9 indicates you are at a healthy"
        }
    }

}
```

the result for `ComplexAlert` will be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately the app can’t work with a button. The showTip() triggers based off some results displayed in a Text. It then returns one of the Bools as true which should show an Alert. IDK why Apple made this somewhat complicated in SwiftUI

Comment: @Dewan ok, so.. the example ```ComplexAlertWith3Variables``` in code snippet makes the same, it shows alert only when one of 3 bool variables changes to true. And they can change everywhere, it doesn't matter do you change it with button or in some function. Try to add your ```showTip``` function and call it from somewhere. - the result will be the same

Comment: I actually read what you said earlier and made it work with my code. Pretty similar to the way you did it pretty much. Thank you very much! This is an excellent way to do this.